# How do I safely remove the .copyarea.db files?

Tags: clearcase

I see .copyarea.db files popping up in my ClearCase snapshot directories.  I understand that deleting the file may cause some problems.  How can I get rid of these files safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All CCWeb views have a storage stored at the CCRC server (which in turn communicates with the VOB server).
That differs from classic ClearCase views, where the view storage is either on the user's computer, or in a close View Storage server.

Since the clients using CCRC cannot always directly access that view storage (on the CCRC server), it needs "local" view storage, which are defined *within* the CCWeb view, with the `.copyarea.dat` and a `.copyarea.db` directories.

Since you are not the first to getting rid of those directories (.db and .dat), CCRC 7.1 now allows for [.dat directory to be restaured](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21392432), allowing then ClearCase to reassess the status of each file, keeping relevant information in the .db storage directory.

Answer (score 2):

The [first google result](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21119280) about .copyarea.db suggests that deleting those files will confuse ClearCase, causing it to think that your files are hijacked.

Comment: Pardon.  I did look at that page earlier.  I'm going to change my question slightly to "How to safely delete .copyarea.db files?"

Answer (score 2):

The .copyarea.db is removed by ClearCase after I add all the View Private files in a snapshot directory to source control.  It makes sense--ClearCase needs the .copyarea.db file to avoid interpreting the copied files as hijacked, but checking them in removes that ambiguity, so ClearCase no longer needs .copyarea.db and deletes it.

Comment: Good explanation of `.copyarea.db` management. +1. I have completed it by some general explanations in my own answer.